# How do I convert the following to char [ ]?

Tags: c, string, operating-system

I used strcpy and sprintf to convert some values (e.g. long decimal) to the attributes of ar_hdr struct.  When I opened the archive, it looks like:

```
0000000    2   -   s   .   t   x   t  \0  \0  \0  \0  \0  \0  \0  \0  \0
0000020    1   3   7   4   0   8   7   6   3   2  \0  \0   5   0   1  \0
0000040   \0  \0   2   0  \0  \0  \0  \0   1   0   0   6   4   4  \0  \0
0000060    8   2  \0  \0  \0  \0  \0  \0  \0  \0   `  \n   2   2   2   2
0000100    2   2   2   2   2   2   2   2   2   2   2   2   2   2   2   2
*
0000140    2   2   2   2  \n   2   2   2   2   2   2   2   2   2   2   2
0000160    2   2   2   2   2   2   2   2   2   2   2   2   2   2   2   2
0000200    2   2   2   2   2   2   2   2   2   2   2   2   2  \n        
0000216
```

I would like to replace all the "\0" when " " (just an empty space).  Can someone give me a hint on how to fix this?  Thanks.
Below is some of the code I wrote.

```
int main (int argc, char **argv)
{
    char *archive = argv[1];
    char *read_file = argv[2];

    int in_fd;
    int out_fd;

    //char title[] = ARMAG;   //constant define in ar.h
    char buf[BLOCKSIZE];
    char tmpBuf[BLOCKSIZE];

    int num_read;
    int num_written;

    struct stat stat_file;
    struct ar_hdr my_ar;

    FILE *fp;

    //open read_file (i.e., text file)
    if (stat(read_file, &stat_file) == -1){
        perror("Error in Stat");
        exit(-1);
    }


    //open read file
    in_fd = open(read_file, O_RDONLY);
    if (in_fd == -1) {
        perror("Canot open/create output file");
        exit(-1);
    }

    //assign file info to struct dhr (my_ar)
    //all my_ar attributes = char []
    strcpy(my_ar.ar_name, read_file);
    sprintf(my_ar.ar_date, "%ld", stat_file.st_mtimespec.tv_sec);
    sprintf(my_ar.ar_uid, "%ld", (long)stat_file.st_uid);
    sprintf(my_ar.ar_gid, "%ld", (long)stat_file.st_gid);
    sprintf(my_ar.ar_mode, "%o", stat_file.st_mode);
    sprintf(my_ar.ar_size, "%lld", stat_file.st_size);
    strcpy(my_ar.ar_fmag, ARFMAG);




    //0666 - open archive
    out_fd = open(archive, O_CREAT | O_WRONLY | O_APPEND, 0666);
    if (out_fd == -1) {
        perror("Canot open/create output file");
        exit(-1);
    }


    //write my_ar struct to archive
    //num_written = write(out_fd, title, sizeof(title));
    off_t curpos = lseek(out_fd, SEEK_CUR, 0);  //get current position
    if(curpos == 0) {                           //if it is at beginning, it must be a new file
        num_written = write(out_fd, ARMAG, SARMAG);
        num_written = write(out_fd, &my_ar, sizeof(my_ar));
    }
    else
    {
        num_written = write(out_fd, &my_ar, sizeof(my_ar));
    }


    //add the file content to archive
    off_t in_fd_pos = lseek(in_fd, 0, SEEK_CUR);
    while ((num_read = read(in_fd, buf, BLOCKSIZE)) >0) {
        num_written = write(out_fd, buf, BLOCKSIZE);

        if (num_written != num_read) {
            perror("Error writing file");
            exit(-1);
        }
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: All NUL to a space? `ptr = str; do { ptr = memchr(ptr, 0, length); if (ptr) *ptr++ = ' '; } while (ptr);`

Comment: They way you are doing this seems very odd. What is expected in the structure? Should the values be left padded or right padded? Should they be padded with spaces or nulls? Using width specifiers and printing to a buffer before copying that over your structure seems like the best solution to your problem - but I'm not quite sure if the problem is actually what I think it is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code appears to write some text into some fixed length strings inside a struct, but you don't provide a definition for `struct ar_hdr`, so I can't be sure.

You then dump the entire struct into a file, but because each string is nul-terminated, and because there are uninitialized values between the strings (that also happen to contain nul-characters, by chance), you're getting unwanted junk in your output.

I'd suggest that you *don't* just dump memory into files. It's far better to do the job properly. How about writing the data to file like this:

```
FILE *out_file = fdopen(out_fd);  /* or use fopen in the first place */
fprintf("%s %s %s %s %s %s", my_ar.ar_name, my_ar.ar_date, my_ar.ar_uid,
        my_ar.ar_gid, my_ar.ar_mode, my_ar.ar_size);
```

If the fixed length strings are still required then look up the field-width modifiers in the printf docs.

Better yet, don't store the data as strings at all, but just print them directly from (a copy of) the original data.

Answer (score 1):

According to the man page of `sprintf()`:

> Upon successful return, these functions return the number of
>   characters printed (excluding  the `null` byte used to end output to
>   strings).

So, one `'\0'` is added by `sprintf()` for each member field. The rest of `'\0'`s for each member field may be due to the initialized values of `my_ar`. You could run an `expt` to see if that is the case by init `my_ar` to a `non-null` value.

`sprintf()` returns a value on how many characters were written. So, you could replace `'\0'` by space using that field.

Comment: Thank you for the tip. Can you please give me more details on how I can init my_ar to a non-null value? Also, How can I replace \0 by space? Sorry, I'm very new to C and programming.

Comment: + to answer, please [view this](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/17792319/revisions) the formatting I given to your answer.

Comment: @Grijesh Chauhan: I'm not clear on how to replace '\0' by space. Can you give me more hints? Thank you.

Comment: @user2203774 I said that I voted and formatted your answer (because it correct), I also want you to learn formatting So I said `view this` that is a link in above comment